# How to resize image on fly(express and S3)

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, image-resizing

I am tring to get image from url and then to resize on fly without saving

```
var request = require('request');
    request
            .get('s3url')
            .on('response', function (response) {
                console.log(response) // 200
                console.log(response.headers['content-type']) // 'image/png'
            })
            .pipe(res)
```

I can now return same picture with `request` lib but how can I manipulate it and then return as response?

Comment: so how did you manage to resolve it? Could you please provide the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several npm modules that do resizing one example is [`sharp`](https://github.com/lovell/sharp). You can use it in this way (example taken from the API documentation).

```
var transformer = sharp()
    .resize(300)
    .on('info', function(info) {
        console.log('Image height is ' + info.height);
    });

readableStream.pipe(transformer).pipe(res);
```

the `readableStream` would be the stream of your original picture.

Comment: Thanks! Is possible to do the same with `Jimp` https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp ?

Comment: Sadly `jimp` does not support streams. So you can't use it without a workaround.

Comment: `jimp` is also much slower: http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/performance/

Answer (score 0):

Full example with Sharp. check the github link: https://github.com/surojitp/imageResizeOnTheFly

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import sharp from "sharp";
import got from "got";


app.get('/',(req, res, next) =>{
    
    let image = req.query.src ? req.query.src : 'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/businessman-hand-writing-demo-marker-business-concep-concept-96434578.jpg';
        
    let width = parseInt(req.query.width ? req.query.width : 100); 
    let height = parseInt(req.query.height ? req.query.height : 100);

        
    var transformer = sharp()
            .resize(width, height)
            .on('info', function(info) {
                // console.log('Image height is ' + info.height);
            });

    /********* Using GOT */
    got.stream(image).pipe(transformer).pipe(res);
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Example: http://localhost:8080/?src=https://buket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/defaultimg.png&&height=200&&width=200