# Is it possible to compress the base64 content of an image without storing it at some location?

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm stuck into a dilemma & I have to resolve it without using the help of physical storage. Explaining in detail, I am getting base64 of an image in response from a server connected via VPC. I have to compress that base64 and send it to mobile. I'm not sure if it is even possible without physically storing it at some temp location in a resized format & converting it back to base64 or I might be missing some technical understanding here.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Decoding the base64 might be sufficient compression, especially if the image was itself stored in a compressed format.

Comment: Yes decoding would compress it by 25% but what if the image is of 1MB size and i want to resize and compress it down to 200kb...probably a lightweight version of that image only for display purpose in mobile

Comment: Does [How to resize image on fly(express and S3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743479/how-to-resize-image-on-flyexpress-and-s3) help?

Comment: Looks like good example, let me try and see the result. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you so much man. This module is really awesome. It helped me do the stuff at buffer level without needing to save the content as image locally.